# is call_user_func_array a security risk when allowing a user to pass the method name and params?

Tags: php, security

here is Official example:

```
class foo {
    function bar($arg) {
        echo __METHOD__, " got $arg\n";
    }
}

$foo = new foo;
call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("three"));
```

And this is my code look like:

```
call_user_func_array(array($foo, $_POST["A"]), array($_POST["B"]));
```

we can controller $_POST["A"] and $_POST["B"], $foo maybe another class.

my questions is "is this safe? and will not result RCE problem?"

Comment: This is not safe at all, it allows the user to execute any method with any argument. Is there any reason you need this flexibility?

Comment: in fact, i learning php code aduit. in this git repo https://github.com/thenugespeaks/missiontoditmars2/blob/9499d994c871b1331177bef182d113e2b04b6154/wwwroot/wp-includes%5Cjs%5Ctinymce%5Cplugins%5Cspellchecker%5Crpc.php ,it use  call_user_func_array(array($spellchecker, $input['method']), $input['params']), $spellchecker->$input['method']($input['params']) ,  look like safe , i can not search RCE method in this case. so i ask one method to attack like this.

Comment: hello, Is there any mistake in my understanding?